# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis" *Cause: *Action:

Tags: sql, oracle

getting error while creating table, the error is on Identity for missing Parenthesis.

```
create table Student (
StudentID number(8) primary key identity (1,1),
FirstName varchar2(50),
LastName varchar2(50),
Subject varchar2(20),
Fees float
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
create table Student (
StudentID number(8) primary key,
FirstName varchar2(50),
LastName varchar2(50),
Subject varchar2(20),
Fees float
);
```

But if you want the studentID field to be automatically generated via an IDENTITY, then it would be more like this -

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    studentid NUMBER
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1,
    CONSTRAINT student_pk PRIMARY KEY ( studentid ) ENABLE...
 -- add your other columns
);
```

Comment: Explicit Not null constraint on studentid is not required as primary key constraint will apply not null constraint implicitly.

Comment: Doesn't hurt anything either, but yeah you're right